# Run Ant target within Gradle task

Tags: ant, gradle

I am pretty new in using Gradle, and I have some troubles. I'm trying to import ant script into gradle and then run some ant targets. Then I cal gradle task in Jenkins.

So far what I have:

```
task MyAnt<< {
    ant.importBuild 'build.xml'
    def antTargetsNames = ant.references.get("ant.targets").collect { it.name }
    println "\nAnt Targets: ${antTargetsNames}\n" 
    call Ant traget, e.g. compileAnt
}
```

Basically I print all targets now, but I do not know how to call ant target within gradle task.
Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ant.importBuild 'build.xml'` has to happen outside the task action. The result is that you'll get a Gradle task for each Ant target, which can be executed from the command line. Tasks can't execute other tasks but can depend on them (e.g. `myTask.dependsOn(someAntTarget)`, again outside a task action. For more information, check the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html) and the samples in the `gradle-all` distribution.

Comment: Yes. I don't consider `ant.importBuild` very useful in the real world though, as it will give you a glorified Ant build, not a proper Gradle build. However, the ability to use Ant tasks from Gradle is very useful.